# How to colour specific dots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to scatter the following variables (N1 and N2)

Here is a small sample of my data.

```
df<-read.table (text=" N1 N2
60  19
55  77
45  35
70  66
30  47
60  26
50  55
70  96
60  67
40  56
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to colour circles when the differences between N1 and N2 is >20%

I calculate the difference : (N2-N1)/N1*100 to get percentages for each row. The signs of negative or positive are ignored (absolute number)

The outcome is similar to this :

[image]

That would be good if we could have the confidence intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `ggplot2`. Compute the percentage and store the comparison you want in a logical variable that can be used for coloring the scatter plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>%
  mutate(Perc=abs((N2-N1)/N1*100),
         Col=!Perc>20) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=N1,y=N2,color=Col))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm',aes(group=1))+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you,  Green should read red and Red should read Green, Can I have The CI as well. Could we do better?

Comment: @user330 Let me update the code for color, for CI you need standard deviation or how to you want to add CI?

Comment: @user330 Updated colors, we can compute the global SD and mean and add as lines. For each point I do not see a viable way to compute SD

Comment: @user330 That is possible, one moment!

Comment: @user330 Updated, let me know if that works!